# Registering dynamically loaded DLLs with Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, nrules

I  have this piece of code in the constructor of a class.

```
        rules = rulesEngineRepository.GetRules(x => x.Enabled);
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            var ruleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom($"{rule.AssemblyName}.dll");
            kernel.Register(Component.For(ruleAssembly.GetType()).LifestyleSingleton());
        }
```

The Assembly.LoadFrom() statement works as expected and loads the assembly correctly, but the following kernel.Register() call doesn't appear to register the component.

When it's accessed later on, Castle.Windsor blows up with a "failed to activate" and an inner exception of "No component for supporting the service...".  Clearly, the component isn't registered.

Could someone point out where I'm going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What are you registering? What are you resolving?

Answer (score 0):

The `Component.For(ruleAssembly.GetType())` will create a component for `System.Reflection.Assembly`. I'm guessing what you wanted was to either have something using `ruleAssembly.GetExportedTypes()` or something along the lines of:

```
container.Register(
  Classes.FromAssembly(ruleAssembly)
    .FurtherConfigurationHere()
)
```